# C# Check if a string is of type ABC123

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to check if a string is of type ABC123.

- The length of the string must be 6.
- Only letters and numbers are allowed.
- The first three values of the string must be letters.

This is what I have done. How can I improve the code?

```
    private void ValidationOfFlightCode(string flightCode)
    {
        if (flightCode.Length == 6)
        {
            bool state = Regex.IsMatch(flightCode, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
            if (state)
            {
                bool isLetter = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    isLetter = Char.IsLetter(flightCode, i);
                    if (!isLetter)
                        break;
                }
                if (isLetter)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(flightCode + ": " + state);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The letters must be before the numbers");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Only letters and numbers are allowed!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Flight Code must be 6 characters long");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need specific error messages for each error? Otherwise this regex will do the job: `[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{3}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$
//  ^     ^      ^      ^
//  |     |      |      |
//  |     |      |      +-- Three times
//  |     |      +--------- Letters or digits
//  |     +---------------- Three times
//  +---------------------- Only letters
```

If `IsMatch` on this regex returns `false`, you could do further validations to see what's wrong.

> How can I improve the code?

You can create a list of pairs of regexes and error messages. Each regex should be more restrictive than the previous one. Go through the list, and try matching the code against the regex. If there is *no* match, print the error message and exit the loop. For example, you can do this:

- `^.{6}$` - "The code must contain six characters"
- '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$' - "The characters must be alhpanumeric"
- '^[[a-zA-Z]{3}.{3}$' - "The first three characters must be letters"

Comment: What is the regex if I only want numbers in the last three characters?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to be so specific about what error is occurring, you could write a regexp that catches the entire specification in one go. I'll assume that the form is always AAAXXX, i.e. three letters and thre numbers (and never a letter among the last three characters), but it's easy to adapt if letters are OK there too.

```
bool isOK = Regex.IsMatch(flightCode, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$");
```

That regex also imposes the ordering of the characters, and the total string length. However, I would go even further and do this as an extension method on the `string` type:

```
public static class FlightCodeValidationExtensions {
    public static bool IsValidFlightCode(this string str) {
        return Regex.IsMatch(flightCode, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$");
    }
}
```

Now, you can validate the string as a flightcode by simply calling `str.IsValidFlightCode()`, as long as you've imported the namespace where the above class resides (and there are several add-ons to Visual Studio that will do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before the length check you can also do a null check, depending on how this function gets its input.

On a side note, i personaly find Messages boxes annoying. It might be better With some sort of a Label next to the textbox that shows a error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you also want to keep a possibility to give an user a feedback about the error?
Personally i would probably test all these conditions in one single regular expression, like the one posted above. And then if it fails i would test it for number of other expressions to get a reason of failure. I trust more to regular expressions than to some test iterations.

Answer (score 0):

- how about the 2nd 3 characters? you don't test those
- 1st 3 must be "US letters"? can't be any other locale? (like "é", or Chinese/Japanese/Hebrew/etc)

for improvements:
* You can skip the regular expression as you'll do char.IsLetter anyway. You can also add char.IsLetterOrDigit for the 2nd 3 chars (or char.IsDigit if those 3 must be numeric)
* also can cut out 'else' branches and throw a single error message when your for fails, and giving the required format in general ("Flight code must be 6 chars long, 3 digits & 3 numbers such as ABC123"). this way you can speed up a bit as you'll test the value one time only (if-then-else)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to match only the last three characters of a string:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("flightCode", @"[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$");
```